# Creating new "userCategory" object under "User" when signup is successful

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I want to create a new `userCategory` object under the `User` class when someone signs up for an account in my iOS app. This way, every user has multiple instances of the `userCategory` object associated with their account. I'm using Parse for my backend.

I figured I would do it by having the app call a cloud function that initializes the object under the `User` class when signup is complete, as seen in my JS code. My issue is that I'm getting an error stating that `User is not defined at main.js:16:31`. I'm not sure how I would reference a class in JS that is created from objective-c code.

Function is called in the `(void)signUpViewController:(PFSignUpViewController *)signUpController didSignUpUser:(PFUser *)user` method.

Objective-C code:

```
#import "DefaultSettingsViewController.h"

@implementation DefaultSettingsViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if ([PFUser currentUser]) {
        //[welcomeLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Welcome Back %@!", [[PFUser currentUser] username]]];
        NSLog(@"PFUser is not current user");

    } else {
        NSLog(@"PFUser is current user");
        //[welcomeLabel setText:@"Not logged in"];
    }
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    if (![PFUser currentUser]) { // No user logged in
        // Create the log in view controller
        PFLogInViewController *logInViewController = [[PFLogInViewController alloc] init];
        [logInViewController setDelegate:self]; // Set ourselves as the delegate
        [logInViewController setFacebookPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"friends_about_me", nil]];
        [logInViewController setFields: PFLogInFieldsUsernameAndPassword | PFLogInFieldsLogInButton | PFLogInFieldsTwitter | PFLogInFieldsFacebook | PFLogInFieldsSignUpButton | PFLogInFieldsPasswordForgotten];

        // Create the sign up view controller
        PFSignUpViewController *signUpViewController = [[PFSignUpViewController alloc] init];
        [signUpViewController setDelegate:self]; // Set ourselves as the delegate

        // Assign our sign up controller to be displayed from the login controller
        [logInViewController setSignUpController:signUpViewController];

        // Present the log in view controller
        [self presentViewController:logInViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];
    } else {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"login" sender:self];
    }

}


#pragma mark - PFLogInViewControllerDelegate

// Sent to the delegate to determine whether the log in request should be submitted to the server.
- (BOOL)logInViewController:(PFLogInViewController *)logInController shouldBeginLogInWithUsername:(NSString *)username password:(NSString *)password {
    // Check if both fields are completed
    if (username && password && username.length && password.length) {
        return YES; // Begin login process
    }

    [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Missing Information" message:@"Make sure you fill out all of the information!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
    return NO; // Interrupt login process
}

// Sent to the delegate when a PFUser is logged in.
- (void)logInViewController:(PFLogInViewController *)logInController didLogInUser:(PFUser *)user {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}

// Sent to the delegate when the log in attempt fails.
- (void)logInViewController:(PFLogInViewController *)logInController didFailToLogInWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Failed to log in...");
}

// Sent to the delegate when the log in screen is dismissed.
- (void)logInViewControllerDidCancelLogIn:(PFLogInViewController *)logInController {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}


#pragma mark - PFSignUpViewControllerDelegate

// Sent to the delegate to determine whether the sign up request should be submitted to the server.
- (BOOL)signUpViewController:(PFSignUpViewController *)signUpController shouldBeginSignUp:(NSDictionary *)info {
    BOOL informationComplete = YES;

    // loop through all of the submitted data
    for (id key in info) {
        NSString *field = [info objectForKey:key];
        if (!field || !field.length) { // check completion
            informationComplete = NO;
            break;
        }
    }

    // Display an alert if a field wasn't completed
    if (!informationComplete) {
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Missing Information" message:@"Make sure you fill out all of the information!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
    }

    return informationComplete;
}

// Sent to the delegate when a PFUser is signed up.
- (void)signUpViewController:(PFSignUpViewController *)signUpController didSignUpUser:(PFUser *)user {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

    [PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"userCategoryCreate"
                       withParameters:@{}
                                block:^(NSNumber *ratings, NSError *error) {
                                    if (!error) {
                                        //userCategory created
                                    }
                                }];
}

// Sent to the delegate when the sign up attempt fails.
- (void)signUpViewController:(PFSignUpViewController *)signUpController didFailToSignUpWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Failed to sign up...");
}

// Sent to the delegate when the sign up screen is dismissed.
- (void)signUpViewControllerDidCancelSignUp:(PFSignUpViewController *)signUpController {
    NSLog(@"User dismissed the signUpViewController");
}



- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end
```

Cloud Code Javascript:

```
   // Creation of initial userCategory object

    Parse.Cloud.define("userCategoryCreate", function(request, response) {

    var userCategory = Parse.Object.extend("userCategory");

    var newUserCategory = new userCategory();
    newUserCategory.set("categoryId", "9355");

    newUserCategory.set("parent", User);


    newUserCategory.save();


    });
```

And this is how my Parse dashboard looks:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not telling the script what "User" is. If you want the current user, use `Parse.User.current()` instead

```
   // Creation of initial userCategory object

    Parse.Cloud.define("userCategoryCreate", function(request, response) {
        var userCategory = Parse.Object.extend("userCategory");
        var newUserCategory = new userCategory();
        newUserCategory.set("categoryId", "9355");
        newUserCategory.set("parent", Parse.User.current());
        newUserCategory.save();
    });
```

Comment: Ahh I see what you mean. Would I use that in place of `Parse.Cloud.define()` or `Parse.Object.extend ()`?